# What does this Node.js REST API app snippet do?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, api, web-applications

```
function createData(req, res) {
  console.log('trying to store Data.')
  console.log('testing log ' + req.body.productID)

  app.create_data(req, function (err, response) {
    console.log('while returning' + response)
    console.log('while returning error is '+err)

    if(!err){
        var jsonString = {}
        jsonString['Result'] = "Success"

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        res.send(JSON.stringify(jsonString))
        res.end()
    }
    else{
        var jsonString = {}
        jsonString['Error'] = err.description

        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        res.send(JSON.stringify(jsonString))
        res.end()
    }
  })
}
```

1. I've seen the following code for creating data in a REST API example. I can't understand a few things about it, can anyone please explain the overall purpose of this snippet?
2. What is `jsonString['Result'] = "Success"` doing, since we have initialized with an empty string?
3. These is a GET API, where is my code getting data from the text fields?
4. What does `app` mean in this Node.js snippet?
5. Why are we giving the same name that we already gave, like so: `app.app.create_data`?

Answer (score 1):

1. This code snippet will create a JSON response to some API route.
2. This line assigns the string value `"Success"` to the `jsonString` object under the `'Result'` key. It's a way to store key-value pairs in a [JavaScript Object](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp).
3. This snippet doesn't send anything more, than just what the `jsonString` object holds, which is either `"Result"` with the `"Success"` message or `"Error"` with a description. It will be converted to JSON and will be sent as a response:`res.send(JSON.stringify(jsonString))`.
4. Generally 'app' is an instance of [some HTTP server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect) in Node.js
5. It's just a structuring/naming practice, this can be highly different from project-to-project.

---

#### To get started with Node.js apps, check out these links:

- [Learn Node.js in 1 hour](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TlB_eWDSMt4) YouTube video
- [Gettings started with Node.js apps](http://excellencenodejsblog.com/getting-start-nodejs-101-helloworld/) blog series
- [Creating a simple REST API tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/wapjude/creating-a-simple-rest-api-with-expressjs-in-5min-bbtmk51mq) blog entry with Express.js